# Vhost access error / wamp

Tags: windows, wamp, wampserver, mod-vhost-alias

I have a big problem with my vhost installation with my wamp server when i want to load my website, it display this :

> "Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server."

i have seen a lot of tutorials and i have try this, and it didn't work well :

in : `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.23\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName panierdesaison79
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/panierdesaison79/
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/panierdesaison79/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
```

In : `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

```
#blablabla
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost

    127.0.0.1       panierdesaison79
    ::1             panierdesaison79
```

How it couldn't work?

Comment: Try `DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/panierdesaison79`

Comment: And dont forget to restart Apache every time you change any of these files

Comment: Did you also know that WAMPServer 3 has a easy to use tool to create all the Virtual Host config for you. [See this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) All you need to do is create the folder to hold the site